# Resizing Live Paint Pixel Art

Tags: adobe-illustrator, resize, pixel, smartobject

I tried doing some pixel art, used the Rectangular Grid Tool, used Live Paint to create the art and then I expanded it from Object>Live Paint>Expand. I'm using 2 colors, black and red. My problem is that when I'm trying to resize this expanded art work as a group it ads one line of gray-white-red pixels.

[image: pixel art]
<sup>Click image for full resolution</sup>

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this effect only present in Illustrator (and, possibly, Acrobat, if you save as a *.pdf), or does it persist in a print or a hi-res *.jpg?

Answer (score 1):

It's no longer "Live Paint" art if you've clicked the `Expand` button.

I'm not seeing any extra line specifically.

If you are referring to the thin grey line within the black areas, that is a result of on-screen anti-aliasing. Even vector art needs to use the pixels of your monitor to show you things. Those hairlines should disappear when printed or if exported/saved for Web with the "art optimized" anti-alias setting.

You may find it very helpful to **turn off anti-aliasing in the prefs** if you are creating pixel art.